# Set Filezilla so that it view/edit by default instead of downloading

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filezilla

I'm working on Ubuntu and using FileZilla. I was wondering that when I doubleclick on a remote file, if it was possible to open it in an editor instead of downloading it. (Automatically View/Edit instead of Download option).

Ideas?

Answer (score 11):

Open FileZilla, enter **Edit → Settings** (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>) and to go **Interface → File lists**.

There, in **Double-click action** you can set the default action for double-clicking files and directories:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Note that to edit the file, it has to be downloaded...